# Is there a way to change '#' in url to something else like '#_'?

Tags: angular

I enabled useHash option in my app-routing.module.ts. So it turns my url into something like this: http://localhost:4200/#/ .

```
 @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true, })],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

How to modify my module to turn the url to this: `http://localhost:4200/#_/ ?` I want to keep every feature of angular routing so I want to avoid to write a custom one.

Comment: You could start each route path with the `_` character. Any particular reason you're using hash routes? Writing for older browsers?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The hash is effectively a relic that has to be used for old browsers to be able to do SPA if they don't support the history API.

Comment: Oh I see I thought # is required to keep the app as one page application. Without that ng compiler generates files for every route. Btw (O365) Microsoft Teams is created in angular and I have seen they using _# instead of # on their browser implementation ( https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/conversations/ ). I searched how or why they did that but I have found nothing.